# How to run a LoadFromFile command using pom.xml in MAVEN?

Tags: maven

I am working on a tool called Windchill. I have prepared a build to load few attributes through xml files.To load these xml files i use the following command.

For eg: windchill wt.load.LoadFromFile -d C:\ptc\Windchill_10.1\Windchill\loadFiles\pdmlink\itc\attributes\Attributes.xml -u wcadmin -p wcadmin

Like this I have some 100 commands to run manually on the windchill command prompt. So I basically want to automate the process by executing these commands sequentially using MAVEN  without any much of manual work.

Is there any way to deploy this build. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to take a look at the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) which seemed to be the right choice for what you like to achieve.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <phase>WhatEver</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>windchill </executable>
          <!-- optional -->
          <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
          <arguments>
            <argument>wt.load.LoadFromFile</argument>
            <argument>and so on</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: I have prepared pom.xml in the above format and i am executing the below command in the command prompt:   mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="windchill" [-Dexec.workingdir="C:\mvn\test"] -Dexec.args="wt.load.LoadFromFile -d "C:/ptc/Windchill_10.1/Windchill/loadFiles/pdmlink/itc/attributes/Attributes.xml"  .

Comment: But i am getting the error as : 
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix '[-Dexec.workingdir=C' in the current project
 and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] availabl
e from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository), central
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Answer (score 0):

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>Build</groupId>
        <artifactId>Build_SMB</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <name>SMB PROJECT</name>
        <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <executable>windchill</executable>
              <!-- optional -->
              <workingDirectory>C:/mvn/test</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>wt.load.LoadFromFile</argument>
                <argument>-d</argument>
                <argument>C:/ptc/Windchill_10.1/Windchill/loadFiles/pdmlink/itc/attributes/Attributes.xml</argument>
                <argument>-u</argument>
                <argument>wcadmin</argument>
                <argument>-p</argument>
                <argument>wcadmin</argument>
              </arguments>
               <systemProperties>
                <systemProperty>
                  <key>WT_HOME</key>
                  <value>${env.WT_HOME}</value>
                </systemProperty>
              </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Above is the pom.xml i created